# How to pause a video when clicking out of the pop-up

Tags: css, video, popup

I'm pretty much new to the coding world, and I am working on a website that is going to have a button that is going to play a video from youtube. I have found online how to create the pop-up, but once I click out of the video, it still plays the video and you can hear it playing in the background.

I have tried different things, but still I can't figure out what the problem with my code is. Here's my code:

```css
.lightbox {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.lightbox:target {
 outline: none;
 display: block;
}


#videoModal {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 870px;
  margin:auto;}
  #videoModal .modal-header {
    background: #000;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    height:35px;
margin-bottom: 5px; }
    #videoModal .modal-header h3 {
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   padding:5px;}
  #videoModal .modal-body {
    height: 489px;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: none;
    overflow: hidden; }
  #videoModal .modal-footer:empty {
    display: none !important; }
  #videoModal .close {
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: 0;
    width: 38px; 
border-width: 0px !important;}
```

```html
<a class="vid_link" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="#img1"><img src="http://www.bbk.ac.uk/lib/images/general/PLAY.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;"></a> 


<!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
<div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close full-height" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
    <h3>Mumford and Sons: Broad-Shouldered Beasts</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"><iframe width="870px" height="489px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/84V4AQIZMUg?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
  <div class="modal-footer"></div>
</div></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you are OK with JQuery. You may add the JS code below. 
Make sure to remove src from your video iFrame, since it will be set programmatically when the document is ready. 
Assign an id to the play button; I assumed the id is playBtn.
Since the page tracks the recent play/pause state when refreshing, we need only, at the loading time, to set the src if the button is on the play mode. Upon clicking the play button, we only toggle the src between blank and your video link.
An updated snippet is in the answer, but I know that it is not working in Stackoverflow due to the YouTube API. Hence, I gave this little description to let you know what I did.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isVisible = $('#img1:visible').length;
    var src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/84V4AQIZMUg?rel=0&autoplay=1';

    if(isVisible){
        $('iframe').attr('src', src);
    }


$('#playBtn, #img1').click(function(){      
        $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src')? "": src);
    });

});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isVisible = $('#img1:visible').length;
 var src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/84V4AQIZMUg?rel=0&autoplay=1';

 if(isVisible){
  $('iframe').attr('src', src);
 }


 $('#playBtn, #img1').click(function(){      
         $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src')? "": src);
     });
 
 });
```

```css
.lightbox {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.lightbox:target {
 outline: none;
 display: block;
}


#videoModal {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 870px;
  margin:auto;}
  #videoModal .modal-header {
    background: #000;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    height:35px;
margin-bottom: 5px; }
    #videoModal .modal-header h3 {
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   padding:5px;}
  #videoModal .modal-body {
    height: 489px;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: none;
    overflow: hidden; }
  #videoModal .modal-footer:empty {
    display: none !important; }
  #videoModal .close {
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: 0;
    width: 38px; 
border-width: 0px !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="vid_link" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="#img1"><img src="http://www.bbk.ac.uk/lib/images/general/PLAY.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;"></a> 


<!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
<div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close full-height" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
    <h3>Mumford and Sons: Broad-Shouldered Beasts</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"><iframe width="870px" height="489px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
  <div class="modal-footer"></div>
</div></a>
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! It worked perfectly well! Really appreciate it!